# What is the best approach to integrate marketo forms with Kentico

Tags: kentico, marketo

I'm new to kentico and I'm trying to integrate marketo Forms 2.0 (contact us page) to a kentico page, Was unable to find any integration samples,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix all the form tag issues using following  code

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-***.marketo.com", "****", 8888, function (form) {
        MktoForms2.$("#formPlaceholder_8888").append(form.getFormElem());
        form.addHiddenFields({ "Industry": document.title });
        form.onSuccess(function (values, followUpUrl) {
            return false;
        });
    });
 <div id="formPlaceholder_8888">&</div>
```

Replace the *** and 888 with correct values of the script.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options to integrate a Marketo Form on a Kentico page. The first option is to place the form embed code generated by Marketo directly in the HTML of the Kentico page. The second option is to integrate a Marketo Form as an iFrame on the Kentico page. The third option would be to use your own form on the Kentico page, and then [send this data to Marketo using a server-side form post](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/server-side-form-post/).

Comment: Is is possible to get code sample for embedded method, I tried to add via static html content, but not working, I'm suspecting that the issue is due to multiple form tags.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://developers.marketo.com/assets/Forms2DevExamples/example1.html) from the Marketo Forms developer documentation. Please take a look at the page's source code to see how the script is loaded.

The form tag should have an id attribute matching the id parameter referenced in the loadForm method. This should address any issues associated with multiple form tags.

Comment: what I did was change the master page form tag id as same as marketoform tag id and keep the marketoform form with in the static html control. but i'm planning to integrate multiple marketo forms, does this Id change impacting that

Comment: The loadForm method will load the specific form requested by the id parameter. When the form layout is returned after the loadForm method is called, it looks for a form tag with that specific id, and then appends the form layout there. If you have multiple Marketo Forms on the same page. You would need to make multiple loadForm method calls with the specific form ids needed. You would also need individual form tags for each unique form id.

Comment: Nested forms are invalid HTML, which is what I believe your options 1 and 2 are attempting to do.